# Custom Sorting Order Methods in R?

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a data.frame d with a date column in the format d$date[1]="01-Jan-09" throught to d$date[1825]="31-Dec-13". When I use order to sort it,

```
d[order(as.Date(d$date,format="%d%b%y")),]
```

It correctly sorts in chronological order, however I'd like it to sort it ignoring the years.

I'd like the out put of a sort to "01-Jan-09", "01-Jan-10", "01-Jan-11" , ... , "31-Dec-11", "31-Dec-12", and finally "31-Dec-13".

Is there an easy way of achieving this order without making a custom function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave the year out of your `format` specification for order:

```
d <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("2009-01-01"),to=as.Date("2013-12-31"),by=1)
head(d[order(format(d,"%m%d"))])
[1] "2009-01-01" "2010-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01"
[6] "2009-01-02"
```

Comment: @MichaelBird You're welcome. Note that I've edited this to use the month first otherwise you will get all of the first of the months before the seconds, etc

Answer (score 2):

Use `format`

```
dat <- c("31-Dec-12","01-Jan-10", "01-Feb-11", "01-Jan-09" , "31-Dec-11")

dat <- as.Date(dat,format="%d-%b-%y")

dat[order(format(dat, "%y%m%d"))]
[1] "2009-01-01" "2010-01-01" "2011-02-01" "2011-12-31" "2012-12-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
days <- seq(ymd("2009-01-01"), ymd("2013-01-01"), by = "1 day")
days[order(month(days), day(days), year(days))]
```

HTH